# How to draw stack of prism in a pyramid?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw this picture

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{100}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\h{5}
\path (-\a,-\a,0) coordinate (A) (-\a,\a,0) coordinate (B)
(\a,\a,0) coordinate (C) (\a,-\a,0) coordinate (D)
(0,0,\h) coordinate (T);
%\foreach \point/\position in {A/below,B/right,C/below,D/above,T/above}{\fill (\point) circle (1.5pt);\node[\position=1.5pt] at (\point) {$\point$};}
\draw[thick] (T) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (T) -- (B);
\draw[dashed] (T) -- (D) -- (C) (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And got

[image]

How to draw stack of prism in a pyramid?

Comment: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1430

Comment: In the above topanswer.xyz link, `auto dashed` is the most important, neither maths nor 3D beauty, right?

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the possibility of showing the visibility playing with the opacity (instead of dashed lines), the pyramid will be very easy. The important thing now is to order well all the polygons to draw, to show visibility.

For example, creating two `\pic`s, cuboids and triangles, and using `3d` and `perspective` Ti*k*Z libraries:

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\tikzset
{
  my  cuboid/.style={draw=red,fill=white,fill opacity=0.4},
  my pyramid/.style={draw},  % <--- you can fill and change the opacity her too, if you want
  pics/cuboid/.style 2 args={% #1 = base side, #2 = height
    code={%
      \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0      ,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) rectangle ++ (#1,#1);
      \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=-0.5*#1,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,0)       rectangle ++ (#1,#2);
      \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=-0.5*#1,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,0)       rectangle ++ (#1,#2);
      \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2     ,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) rectangle ++ (#1,#1);
      \draw[canvas is xz plane at y= 0.5*#1,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,0)       rectangle ++ (#1,#2);
      \draw[canvas is yz plane at x= 0.5*#1,pic actions] (-0.5*#1,0)       rectangle ++ (#1,#2);
    }},
  pics/triangle/.style 2 args={% #1 = side, #2 = height
    code={\draw[pic actions] (-0.5*#1,0.5*#1,0) -- (0.5*#1,0.5*#1,0) -- (0,0,#2) -- cycle;}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,3d view={160}{20}]
% dimensions
\def\l{2.5} % pyrmaid side
\def\h{3}   % pyramid height
\def\n{9}   % number of cuboids
% pyramid, back
\foreach\i in {90,180}
  \pic[rotate around z=\i,my pyramid] {triangle={\l}{\h}};
% cuboids
\pgfmathsetmacro\hh{\h/(\n+1)}             % cuboid height
\foreach\i in {1,...,\n}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ll{\l*(\n+1-\i)/(\n+1)} % cuboid side
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pp{\hh*(\i-1)}          % cuboid position
  \pic[my cuboid] at (0,0,\pp) {cuboid={\ll}{\hh}};
% pyramid, front
\foreach\i in {0,270}
  \pic[rotate around z=\i,my pyramid] {triangle={\l}{\h}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]